# Avoid SQL deadlocks on CurrentAccountBalance update

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm evaluating PostgreSQL for some personal project.
I was inspirited by it's Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC)

I simulated a basic need - insert transaction and perform a vendor balance update with many threads at the same time, running the SQL commands like:

```
INSERT INTO 
VendorAccountTransactions (VendorId, BalanceBefore, BalanceAfter) 
VALUES (
   1, 
   (SELECT CurrentBalance FROM VendorAccounts WHERE VendorId = 1),  
   (SELECT CurrentBalance FROM VendorAccounts WHERE VendorId = 1) + 19.99
);

UPDATE VendorAccounts SET CurrentBalance = CurrentBalance + 19.99 WHERE VendorId = 1;
```

Any Idea how to avoid deadlocks in such common case?

What is is needed - simply insert the transaction description with "balance before" / "balance after" and update the balance.

It will be used in high load application. 
How to achieve the right result for this simple business need?

Thank you.

**Update:**

Maybe there is any other solution to re-design the database to avoid deadlocks or use some other solution to keep the business need solved?

Comment: You cannot avoid deadlocks, but you can detect them. Just pack your two statements inside `begin` and `commit` , and let the caller check the result (and maybe restart the transaction)

Comment: Can you copy/paste the error messages mentioning a deadlock into your question? What deadlock rate are you getting with what kind of load? (We do about half a million financial transactions per month, and I don't remember ever seeing *one* deadlock in that under PostgreSQL.)

Comment: The statement is inside the transaction. I run the query from C# code in Parallel.For loop. Currently I'm trying to catch the SQL Exception and run the C# method recurrently until the transaction commits without the exception. Let's see how it will work. The error I get: "ERROR: 40P01: deadlock detected" Details: "Process 9183 waits for ShareLock on transaction 61434; blocked by process 9182.
Process 9182 waits for ExclusiveLock on tuple (2,36) of relation 16660 of database 16385; blocked by process 9183."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the update first and include both statements in a transaction. The update will updlock the vendor row and prevent concurrent transactions from entering the transaction (they will wait until the first tran completed as the updlock is not available).

This will effectively serialize access to a given vendor which will ensure consistency.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it helped. Changed the order of this two insert / update queries and no deadlocks any more. I'm able to insert near 1000 records a second, hopefully issuing the same amount of correct balance update. I'll check the expected balance after several thousandth updates to see how correct it works. For now I'm getting connection pool errors after some large period of time, but that's not PostgreSQL issue at all. It's amazing how such simple suggestion helped. I'm still not sure why exactly it helped so much.

Comment: Because you are acquiring the updlock first. All threads acquire it first. And they have to wait for each other because of it.